# Using jQuery's .load() Function within WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm in the process of migrating my HTML website into a WordPress Theme and have the following question:

My current HTML website makes full use of jQuery's `.load()` function, by where I change the content of the page (via a DIV), using `.load()` based on my side menu options selected by the user.

With this, can I still keep this processing within the WordPress version of my site and if so, how would I go about doing this as obviously it's using jQuery library?

Is this something I have in my `header.php` file so that all pages see it?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use javascript within wordpress page editor. I believe you just wrap [RAW]...[/RAW] tags around it.  You would of course need to include the jquery.js file on your pages. You can do it within the same page in the page editor or have it output in one of the global files like the header file, yes.